# Javascript ordering of elements alphabetically via id

Tags: javascript, alphabetical

I have a project that whenever an item is obtained, it goes into an inventory. This is shown on the screen by creation of a paragraph element with an id the same as the item name. The paragraph element is appended to a inventory div. Currently, whenever a new one is added it just adds it below any other already created paragraphs. Is there a way to append it depending on the alphabetical order?
Order, how can I go about checking every time the inventory is updated if the order is right, and if not cause them to move
Relevant code:

```
    createRescDisp: function(item) {
    if (item.para === undefined || item.para === null) {
    item.para = document.createElement('p');
    item.para.setAttribute('class', 'inventoryItem');
    item.para.setAttribute('id', item);
    item.para.innerHTML = item.name + ": " + item.quantity;
    plyrInv.append(item.para);
    } else {
        item.para.innerHTML = item.name + ": " + item.quantity;
    }
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that the id's are unique?

Comment: Yes, can guarantee each Id is unique

Answer (score 1):

You can get the inventory node's `children` and iterate over this nodes. Use  [String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare the id property and [Node.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) to insert the new node just before the corresponding node:

```js
const appendItem = item => {
  const items = inventory.children;
  const para = document.createElement('p'); //<-- create the node
  para.id = item;
  para.textContent = item;
  let position = -1; //--> first position
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const node = items[i];
    if (node.id.localeCompare(item) <= 0) position = i;
  }
  inventory.insertBefore(para, items[position + 1]); //--> if items at position + 1 is undefined will insert the node at the end
};

const btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.onclick = function() {
 const value = document.querySelector("input").value;
 appendItem(value);
}
```

```html
<input />
<button>Add Item</button>
<h3>Items </h3>
<div id="inventory">
  <p id="stone">
    stone
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Trying this way, it doesn't seem to sort correctly.  Using 2 items to pass in, copper or stone, if stone exists first, it sorts it before copper. I can't make rhyme or reason why..

Comment: I updated my answer, You can add the items dynamically, I see that copper is inserted before stone. Run the code snippet and you will see it is working

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I must be absolutely stupid as I can't get it to work once integrating into my code.

Comment: @valosity try to add more parts of your code? Must be something wrong or something you are missing

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to sort all of the items each time you insert something.

```js
const addButton = document.getElementById('add-button');
const textInput = document.getElementById('text-input');
const playerInventory = document.getElementById('player-inventory');
addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // ignore this block, it's just simulating what you're already doing
  {
    const text = textInput.value;
    const newItem = document.createElement('div');
    newItem.setAttribute('id', text);
    newItem.classList.add('inventory-item');
    newItem.innerHTML = text;
    playerInventory.append(newItem);
  }
  
  // get children as array
  const children = Array.from(playerInventory.querySelectorAll('.inventory-item'));
  // sort by id
  children.sort((a,b) => a.getAttribute('id') > b.getAttribute('id') ? 1 : -1);
  // reappend all items in the inventory
  for (const child of children) {
    // elements can only exist once in the DOM so reappending it removes it from its original location
    playerInventory.append(child);
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text-input">
<button id="add-button">add</button>

<div id="player-inventory"></div>
```

You likely have a better way to access the text using `item.name` so you could do the sorting at a higher level.

Comment: So i've tried implementing this. I also have a function that decreases the quantity when another button is pressed. So, the first time around the sort works fine, 2 names im using are "stone" and copper", and the first time around it sorts copper as a and stone as b in the sort function. returning false. Which it sorts it fine, but isnt the copper > than stone alphabetically? Then when I decrease stone by 1, it goes through the sort function again(incase stone is 0, as when it's 0 it deletes it).

Comment: When going through it this second time, it compares stone as a and copper as b, again returning false. Which, should be correct, right? But this is when it appends stone first then copper 2nd, so its incorrect?

Comment: It's worth looking at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for how `array.sort` uses the function you pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone for the help! This problem I couldn't wrap my head around for some time, and no solutions provided worked once implemented into my code.
I finally found the issue that I was passing in objects to the array then trying to create elements as in the order of one of the objects properties, the name(which is the same as the ID) I found 2 issues in what I was trying to do, one being the sort function that other the paragraph elements.
The sort function was sorting the objects correctly based on the info I gave it, but I have to specify a.name (for item.name property, as Callum Morrisson suggested but I didn't quite understand until it finally hit me that the issue and answer have been staring me right in the face the whole time).
The paragraph elements where what I was passing into the array, but I found it easier to just have 1 div that I modify the innerHTML of than creating paragraphs, passing to an array, sorting and printing again.

So, thank you for all the help! My stupidity of the obvious answer kept me frustrated with this issue for days, but I am just learning Javascript and I guess that is the process!